# Replace String in variable from a query using bash

Tags: bash, aws-cli

I am trying to replace a sting from a query using `sed`.It won't replace the variable with  value
Using the below code

```
SQL="CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE <table name>( user_id string, file_name string, file_type string, count string) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'escapeChar'='\\', 'quoteChar'='\"', 'separatorChar'=',') STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat' LOCATION 's3://<bucket name>/<folder name>/$client_id/'";
FINALSQL=$(echo $SQL | sed -e "s/\$client_id/$client_id/g")
```

If I am print `FINALSQL` .It return the below string

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE <table name>( user_id string, file_name string, file_type string, count string) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'escapeChar'='\', 'quoteChar'='"', 'separatorChar'=',') STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat' LOCATION 's3://<bucket name>/<folder name>//'
```

Note:-This is an `Athena` Query using cli command

Did I miss anything in the replacement logic?
please correct if am wrong

Comment: If you can arrange, that `client_id` is an environment variable, a perhaps safer way would be `FINALSQL=$(envsubst <<<$SQL)`.

Comment: @user1934428 clinet_id as an  argument

Comment: If it's an environment variable, `envsubst` uses it. No need to specify it as argument.

Comment: assume 777 as the clinet_id value .exected result like s3://<bucket name>/<folder name>/777/ .how can we replace

Comment: What speaks agains my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the assignment of your variable `SQL`. If you would do a `echo $SQL`, you would see that the variable already does not contain a substring `$client_id`, so there is no surprise that nothing gets substituted.

If you set it as

```
SQL="CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE <table name>( user_id string, file_name string, file_type string, count string) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'escapeChar'='\\', 'quoteChar'='\"', 'separatorChar'=',') STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat' LOCATION 's3://<bucket name>/<folder name>/\$client_id/'"
```

your substitution code works for me.

Another, minor, point is that the way you use `echo` would squeeze any run of spaces into a single space. Not a problem with your current SQL string, but may bite you later.

If you insist in using `sed` for this task, you could either quote the argument to echo, or don't use th unnecessary pipeline. I would simply do a

```
FINALSQL=$(sed -e "s/\$client_id/$client_id/g" <<<$SQL)
```

to accomplish the task. Note that in any case, your *sed* approach will work only as long as `client_id` does not hold regexp characters, which might ruin the substitution.

Comment: getting a syntax error Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Comment: @arj : What do you get in your script when you do a `echo $BASH_VERSION`?

Answer (score 0):

in `SQL` escape `$client_id` like so `\$client_id`

or if possible, use something like `%%client_id%%` throughout

[refer](https://superuser.com/a/1404245)

> > If the current character is , single-quote, or double-quote and it is not quoted, it shall affect quoting for subsequent characters up to the end of the quoted text.
>
> [(source)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03)
>
> Only the outer quotes are not quoted, the rule applies to them. The inner quotes are quoted, they do not affect subsequent characters